# Is it possible to monkey patch Google Analytics to route events somewhere else?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics on my website and I'd like to route all events to my own data storage AND send them through Google Analytics like normal. Ideally this would leave Google Analytics working 100% like normal, but also route the events someplace else.

Is there some function in Google Analytics that I can monkey patch to do this?

Answer (score 0):

While you might be able to hack the send to Google analytics your going to have to try and catch it from analytics somehow I am not a JavaScript developer so cant really help you with that.

I think an easier way of going about this would be to use the [Google analytics api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) to extract the data you need out of and insert it into your own storage that way.

Comment: I was thinking something like `window.gtag_old = window.gtag; window.gtag = myFunction`. Then `myFunction()` simply calls `window.gtag_old` to route the data into Google Analytics and then also routes it elsewhere.